# Validation (CSS 2.0): 'mso-number-format' is not a known CSS property name

Tags: css, export-to-excel

I have inherited for maintenance an ASP .Net app, which among other things exports HTML table to Excel.  The HTML contains constructs like this one: `<td style="mso-number-format:\@;">`
When code is being built, I get error: **“Validation (CSS 2.0): 'mso-number-format' is not a known CSS property name.”**
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

`mso-number-format` is a proprietary (read: non-standard (read: garbage-outside-msoffice)) Microsoft Office CSS property.  You will need to strip these from the export, or better yet remove them from the HTML template altogether.

I found a great resource on the subject that seems to pertain directly to your issue: http://agoric.com/sources/software/htmltoExcel  Apparently they are in favor of the property.

Comment: Well, it's not garbage *per se*, as it fulfills useful tasks inside Office's internal markup. Still, it doesn't belong into exported HTML, I agree.

Comment: Updated to better reflect it's usefulness.

Comment: The link is now broken :-(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I have found the answer to my question. The problem is not with the property '`mso-number-format`', but with the way Visual Studio 2008 was treating it.  The property is non-standard and therefore the validation complaint is legitimate.  However, it should not prevent the project from successfully building.

Visual Studio 2008 by default should treat HTML and CSS errors as warnings.  However, apparently there is some installation glitch. So, VS2008 may treat HTML and CSS errors as errors.  The fix is in: **Tools** | **Options** | *Text Editor* | *HTML* | *Validation*.  For your **Target** check boxes **Show errors** and **as warnings (HTML, CSS)** should be checked.  In my case they were, but errors were treated as errors and not as warnings.  I unchecked the boxes and clicked **OK**.  Then I navigated back to the same place and checked them again and clicked **OK**.  That took care of the problem.